# Scaling shared fields across objects

Tags: account, leads, data, lead-conversion, architecture

Sorry if this is too vague/general of a question.

The org I'm working in has a relationship between its objects of:

Custom Object (lookup) -> Lead

Custom Object (lookup) -> Account

The data flow starts at Custom Object, then it creates a Lead, then eventually an Account is created. Data from the Custom Object gets copied to the Lead and when the Lead is converted it is copied to the Account.

What I don't like about this data flow is if a custom field is on the Custom Object, it has to belong on the Lead and Account too. For example:

Custom_Object__c.Favorite_Food__c

Lead.Favorite_Food__c

Account.Favorite_Food__c

Multiple Custom Object records can belong to one Lead or Account. Whatever is the latest "Favorite Food" from a Custom Object record being created, that is what has to copied to either the Lead.Favorite_Food__c or Account.Favorite_Food__c.

If business adds 10 new data points, I need to add 30 new fields total and continue to make sure the data gets copied from the latest Custom Object record to the appropriate Lead/Account. There is no end in sight for how many new data points need to be added. This doesn't seem scalable. A better approach I'm thinking is creating a brand new object that stories all the unique fields shared among Account, Lead, and the Custom Object. This new object receives all the updates of unique fields and is linked to both the Lead and Account.

Should I keep going down the road of when a new data point needs to be created on the custom object, add it to the Lead and Account? Or is the solution I've outlined in the paragraph above a better route?

Comment: Could it be related to the fact that Lead is not the starting point and usually is on Sales?

Comment: @JefersonChaves it appears so. Custom Object is the starting point, not Lead.

Comment: Could you potentially explore a solution where the Custom Object goes away in favor of, say, a Lead Record Type or a new Lead stage?

Comment: @DavidReed No I wish. The custom object is a history of sorts involving an account or lead. We want to maintain that history.

Comment: What about Field History Tracking? Or a new child object that stores data snapshots or changes in JSON in a Long Text field and renders it using a custom component, rather than actually duplicating the fields?

Comment: @DavidReed interesting idea on JSON Long Text field. Do you have a link to an example of that being done?

Comment: I don't - just an off-the-cuff suggestion I'm afraid.